# How can I force rear camera to open when an app tries to launch front camera

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to programmatically replace the front camera with rear camera. Force it to launch every time. Front camera can be disabled.

There's a way to disable all cameras using the Device Administration API, but I want to keep rear camera only.

Comment: "There's a way to disable all cameras using the Device Administration API, but I want to keep rear camera only" -- even if you were able to disable select cameras this way, that would not necessarily force all camera apps to use a different camera. They might simply not work, because they ask Android for the front-facing camera and Android says there is no front-facing camera to use. Rewiring Android to pretend that the rear camera is *both* the rear camera and the front-facing camera should require you to modify Android and build yourself a custom ROM.

Comment: @CommonsWare So I need to modify Android? Couldn't it be done with root access?

Comment: I cannot rule that out, but I doubt that it will be practical.